# How to create and update the file with extracted a value from Selenium web driver?

Tags: node.js

I extracted some value from the selenium webdriver. I want to save that data into one file.

```
fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', extractedData, 'utf8');
```

I tried with fs, but wasn't able to save the data.

Comment: Have you included `const fs = require('fs');` ?

Comment: Removed the [selenium] tag since none of the code presented is related to Selenium. What error are you getting? Please update your question and post the current error message.

Comment: I faced issue while running into Selenium. The same code is working for node

Comment: Yeah,  i added the require one

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that `extractedData` is too large. You could try using `createWriteStream` to handle larger file content for this case:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt');

// write selenium data to file
writeStream.write(extractedData, 'utf8');
```

If you would like to be notified when the file write is finished, you can also listen for the `finish` event:

```
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Successfully wrote selenium data to file.');
});
```